# Sending Cap'n Proto messages over TCP in C++

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, capnproto

I'm totally new to networking and just started to use [Cap'n Proto](http://capnproto.org/) too.

This is some sample program from [here](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/master/c%2B%2B/samples/addressbook.c%2B%2B):

```
void writeAddressBook(int fd) {
  ::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message;

  AddressBook::Builder addressBook = message.initRoot<AddressBook>();
  ::capnp::List<Person>::Builder people = addressBook.initPeople(2);

  Person::Builder alice = people[0];
  alice.setId(123);
  alice.setName("Alice");
  alice.setEmail("alice@example.com");
  // Type shown for explanation purposes; normally you'd use auto.
  ::capnp::List<Person::PhoneNumber>::Builder alicePhones =
      alice.initPhones(1);
  alicePhones[0].setNumber("555-1212");
  alicePhones[0].setType(Person::PhoneNumber::Type::MOBILE);
  alice.getEmployment().setSchool("MIT");

  Person::Builder bob = people[1];
  bob.setId(456);
  bob.setName("Bob");
  bob.setEmail("bob@example.com");
  auto bobPhones = bob.initPhones(2);
  bobPhones[0].setNumber("555-4567");
  bobPhones[0].setType(Person::PhoneNumber::Type::HOME);
  bobPhones[1].setNumber("555-7654");
  bobPhones[1].setType(Person::PhoneNumber::Type::WORK);
  bob.getEmployment().setUnemployed();

  writePackedMessageToFd(fd, message);
}
```

The last line uses `writePackedMessageToFd()` which takes `fd` as a file descriptor and `message` created by `MallocMessageBuilder`.

I work on Windows with Visual Studio 2017.

I would like to send `message` to a remote server which will answer with a similar Cap'nP object.

The question is how can I send it and receive the answer?

I tried to initialize and create a socket in the following way:

```
    //Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0) {
        cerr << "Can't start WinSock, Error #" << wsResult << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Socket initialized!" << endl;
    }


    //Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Error #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Socket created!" << endl;
    }
```

If everything went fine `socket()` return a file descriptor. 
So I just used 
`writePackedMessageToFd(sock, message)`, but didn't work. 
By the way I don't understand this concept since the socket doesn't "know" which IP and port I want to use. I should specify them when I use the `connect()` function.

I tried to skip the `writePackedMessageToFd()` function. Connected to the server with `connect()` and just used Windows' `send()` function to send the `message`. Something like this:

```
    string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";     //IP Address of server 
    int port = 58661;           //Listening port of server

    //Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0) {
        cerr << "Can't start WinSock, Error #" << wsResult << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Socket initialized!" << endl;
    }


    //Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Error #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Socket created!" << endl;
    }

    //Fill in a hint structure
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    //Connect to server
    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Can't connect to server, Error #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Connected to " << ipAddress << " on port " << port << endl;
    }

    //Send and receive data
    char buf[4096];
    //string mess = "Hello";

    //Send message
    //int sendResult = send(sock, mess.c_str(), mess.size() + 1, 0);
    int sendResult = send(sock, (const char*)&message, sizeof(message) + 1, 0);


    //Wait for response
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
    int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesReceived > 0) {
        cout << "SERVER>" << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
    }


    //Close down everything
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    cout << "Connection closed!" << endl;
```

This one sended something but it was definitely wrong because the server didn't respond.

In brief: I would like to send and receive Cap'n Proto packed messages over TCP connection to a specified IP:port.

How could I accomplish this? I really need some help.

**I would really really appreciate Your help! Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Did you try using the RPC logic that is already built in to Cap'n Proto? Don't write your own from scratch. The example you have shown comes from Cap'n Proto's [Serialization](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html) documentation. Did you look at its [RPC Protocol](https://capnproto.org/rpc.html) and [C++ RPC](https://capnproto.org/cxxrpc.html) documentations at all? "*The Cap’n Proto C++ RPC layer sits on top of the [serialization layer](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html) and implements the [RPC protocol](https://capnproto.org/rpc.html)*"

Comment: If you really want to implement the socket I/O manually, have a look at the "Specification" section at the bottom of the [RPC Protocol](https://capnproto.org/rpc.html) documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There are plenty of good reasons to want to use simple Cap'n Proto serialization on a raw socket, rather than use the whole RPC and async framework. It all depends on the use case. Sometimes the RPC system is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, `socket()` does not return a file descriptor. It returns a Windows `SOCKET`, which is actually a `HANDLE` cast to an integer. On Windows, "file descriptors" are implemented as a compatibility layer in the C runtime library; they are not directly supported by the OS.

You can use `kj::HandleInputStream` and `kj::HandleOutputStream` to perform I/O on sockets on Windows.

```
kj::HandleOutputStream out((HANDLE)sock);
capnp::writeMessage(out, message);
```

And:

```
kj::HandleInputStream in((HANDLE)sock);
capnp::InputStreamMessageReader message(in);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

I'm not sure how can tell to the `sock` socket that which IP:port I would like to use? Should I bind sock to them? (Sorry I'm really new to this stuff :( )

If use my socket initialized and created in the code above then I get an unhandled exception `exception: kj::ExceptionImpl ` in `exception.c++` in line 679.

Am I missing something?

Thank You!!

Comment: please, could you clarify my question? Thank you!

Comment: @Andariel On the server you need to use bind(), listen(), and accept(). On the client you need to use connect(). Sorry, but how to use these is basic networking, not Cap'n Proto specific, and I'm only here to answer Cap'n Proto questions. I suggest posting a new question about this, but keep Cap'n Proto out of it, so that people who don't know Cap'n Proto feel comfortable answering. Alternatively, there are a *lot* of guides about this on the internet.